# Let ABC be an isosceles triangle with AB=AC and incentre I. If AI = 3 and the distance from I to BC is 2. What is the square of the length of BC?

Tags: geometry, triangles

Let ABC be an isosceles triangle with
AB=AC and incentre I. If AI = 3 and the distance from I to BC is 2. What is the square of the length of BC?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I've found that that AI coincides with the altitude of the triangle, so the altitude of the triangle becomes 5.

Comment: You have (if I am not wrong!)  $\overline{BC}^2=80$.

Comment: HINT. Use the angle bisector theorem.

Comment: Have you tried drawing this? Do you know the radius of the circle? Given $A$ and $I$ can you construct the rest? How do you go about doing that? Can you perform equivalent algebraic steps?

Comment: You may use Ed ward's figure if you don't have software to draw pictures. :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Correction of earlier answer**. [image: Square of segment BC]
Draw $IE$ perpendicular to $AB$ at tangent point $E$. Thus $IE=ID=2$, and by Pythagorean theorem $AE=\sqrt{3^2-2^2}=\sqrt5$.

Since $\triangle ABC$  is isosceles, $AI$ extended is perpendicular to $BC$ at midpoint $D$. Hence right triangles $AIE$, $ABD$, with common angle at $A$, are similar, and$$\frac{AE}{EI}=\frac{AD}{DB}$$Substituting,$$\frac{\sqrt5}{2}=\frac{5}{DB}$$making $$DB=\frac{10}{\sqrt5}$$
so that$$BC=2\cdot DB=\frac{20}{\sqrt5}$$ and$$BC^2=\frac{400}{5}=80$$as @Piquito says.

Comment: Ah yes, correction needed.